# AWS R53... how to achieve subnet based web application traffic routing to a region

Tags: amazon-web-services, haproxy, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have DNS service provider(web application) as godaddy with CNAME record resolving to DNS value of application load balancer in @AWS. There is requirement where the webapplication  request from customer network should route/resolve to specific AWS region based on IP address /subnet of customer. Is there a feature in R53 or load balancer to achive this. I see there is such feature in mircosoft @azure traffic manager to do subnet based routing!. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need Route53's geolocation routing, as it works by mapping the IPs from the originating DNS queries to specific AWS resources, like in your case, the loadbalancer.

Here's a link to the resource: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo

Comment: Thanks for your response @Bernardo Salazar. Just read the link. looks like its geo location based routing. The routing policy handles traffic based on user geo location and route a specific ip or dns. Not the one i am looking for. Thank you anyways